# Add Content before footer

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cms, ce-1.9.2.2

I am using magento 1.9.2.2 version. I want to add content from custom module before footer (after all page content) without change any core file and theme files ( .phtml ) .

Comment: Go through the article [http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/) <br/>
It has all the stuff that you require.

Comment: Please read comment in that post. its not working in 1.9 magento version. I tested it. Its Not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is possible with CMS configuration only and no code:**

1. create a static block (CMS > Static Blocks) that contains your content
2. Create a new widget instance (CMS > Widgets) and select your theme
   [image: screenshot (2)]
3. Add Layout Update for page "All Pages" and reference "Page Footer" (this is a container within the page footer) - or "Content" if you want it to be part of the content (i.e. not span over all columns)

[image: screenshot (3)]4. Select static block from (1) in "Widget Options":
[image: screenshot (4)]

5. Save.
6. Clean cache.

---

## Without manual configuration

If this is for an extension, you can use a custom template and the following layout XML instead:

```
<default>
    <reference name="bottom.container">
        <block type="core/template" before="-" name="example" template="your_module/your_template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

The template will be part of the footer, if you want it to be part of the content, see below:

### Add a block programmatically to all pages at the end of the content

Unfortunately, this does **not** work as desired:

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" after="-" name="example" template="your_module/your_template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

This is because the `default` layout handle is applied **before** any page specific layout handles, so although we add the custom block "after all blocks that are already added", the actual content will be added later, after our custom block.

So you have to add your block after all layout XML updates are processed and this is possible with an observer for the `controller_action_layout_load_before` event. The observer will look like this:

```
public function addBlockAfterContent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{  
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $content = $layout->getBlock('content');
    $newBlock = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'example_block_name');
    $newBlock->setTemplate('your_module/your_template.phtml');
    $content->append($newBlock);
}
```

Comment: That would add the block **before** all other layout updates are loaded and would fail because "content" does not exist yet.

Comment: Great, then I was wrong :) I looked at the code and the event is triggered after the XML handles are added, so it makes sense that it works and it's actually a more fitting event than my suggestion

Comment: @ChiragRajput now that everything is clarified in the answer, we can delete the comments

Comment: addBlockAfterContent gives 505 error

Comment: @FabianSchmengler, where do I have to put the observer code `addBlockAfterContent`. In which file?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible with this type of `core/text_list block`.

**`core/text_list`:** Some blocks like content, left, right etc. are of type `core/text_list`. When these blocks are rendered, all their child blocks are rendered automatically without the need to call the `getChildHtml()` method.

Otherwise you have to use `getChildHtml()` in your theme file.

You can use like:

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" after="-" name="test2" template="test.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

Comment: I don't want to change any theme files.

Comment: If you are using core/text_list block then no need to change any theme file or core file. For this you can use reference name "before_body_end" and you can use before="footer-block-name".

Comment: Check improved answer

Comment: I put above code in my module's layout file but not working.

Comment: Pl check the improved answer with block type="core/template"

Comment: It not works. It add the content after the page , but i want to add content before footer.

Comment: Yes it will add the content before body end. For before footer you need to over write the footer file add used the getChildHtml() method there.

Comment: Can you update your answer with code?

Comment: Now try with my improved answer with reference name="content" and after="-"

Comment: Have you checked this solution, is it resolve or not ?

Comment: yes , its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
                <label>New Reference</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="newreference">
            <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Reference: [Add a New Reference in Magento](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/)

Comment: is it possible to create a new reference using a custom module

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions you could use the footer_before position for this.

```
<default>
  <reference name="footer_before">
      <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: I already try it. Its not working :(