# trying to add a phtml file using controller_action_layout_load_before in frontend on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, reference

I am trying to add a phtml file using my custom module in `cart page` only at bottom of content or `above the footer section`

In `/magento1/app/code/local/Maddyboy/Instagramapi/etc/config.xml`

```
<controller_action_layout_load_before>
    <observers>
        <Maddyboy_Instagramapi_layout_load_before>
            <class>Maddyboy_Instagramapi_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore</method>
        </Maddyboy_Instagramapi_layout_load_before>
    </observers>
</controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

In  `/magento1/app/code/local/Maddyboy/Instagramapi/Model/Observer.php`

```
public function controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
     $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
     $content = $layout->getBlock('content');
     $newBlock = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'example_block_name');
     $newBlock->setTemplate('instagramapi/apislider.phtml');
     $content->append($newBlock);  // this line gives 500 error
}
```

if i uncomment the `$content->append($newBlock);` then no errors.

[i followed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132852/add-content-before-footer)
What are errors in my code?

Comment: is it returning any error?

Comment: if in log files then no, only on frontend 505 error

Comment: This page isn’t working

127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: what is `example_block_name`?

Comment: i copied this code from the link mention, i think its creating a new `block`